# Visual Studio - deploy existing website/webAPI to Azure

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-web-app-service

In my VS(2015) solution, I have a ASP.Net website and a WebAPI project. For normal development, I want to use IIS on local machine for dev/test. However, I also want the option to be able to deploy the same sites to Azure on demand.

I know I can 'Convert' an existing project to Azure project from VS. But then it'll become a cloud project only. I don't want to convert it to cloud project.

Is there a way I can use my existing projects in VS and deploy/publish them to Azure?

Thanks

Comment: Yes you just have to create a publish profile. You can download the publish profile from azure and import through visual studio [See More Details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to "convert" your project to an Azure project, you can simply create a publishing profile in Visual Studio and push the build to Azure.

The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-get-started-dotnet) explains how to do this, follow the steps from the "Publish to Azure" section onwards.